# Creating a wp_editor instance with custom tinyMCE buttons

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

Is there a way to define `wp_editor()` with custom tinyMCE buttons?

I've noticed the [wp_editor function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) mentions that one of the `$settings` arguments can be `tinymce (array) (optional) Load TinyMCE, can be used to pass settings directly to TinyMCE using an array()`.

My page uses a number of different instances and I'd like to add certain buttons to certain instances.

For example,

```
Instance #1 : Standard buttons
Instance #2 : bold, italic, ul + (custom) pH, temp
Instance #3 : bold, italic, ul + (custom) min_size, max_size
```

Does anyone know how I'd go about doing this if I've already registered the buttons as tinyMCE plugins as per [this tutorial](http://unrelatedmedia.ca/tutorial/wordpress-adding-custom-buttons-to-tinymce)?

---

**EDIT**

Here's the code I'm using in my plugin file to get this working:

```
function add_SF_buttons() {
    if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages') )
        return;
    if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
        add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'add_SF_buttons_plugins');
    }
}

function add_SF_buttons_plugins($plugin_array) {
    $plugin_array['pH'] = $this->plugin_url . '/js/tinymce_buttons/pH.js';
    $plugin_array['pH_min'] = $this->plugin_url . '/js/tinymce_buttons/pH_min.js';
    $plugin_array['pH_max'] = $this->plugin_url . '/js/tinymce_buttons/pH_max.js';
    return $plugin_array;
}
```

-

```
if (isset($SpeciesProfile)) {
    add_action( 'init' , array (&$SpeciesProfile, 'register_species' ));
    add_action( 'init' , array( &$SpeciesProfile, 'register_species_taxonomies' ));

    add_action( 'init', array (&$SpeciesProfile, 'add_SF_buttons' ));
}
```

-

```
<?php wp_editor( $distribution, 'distribution', array( 'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold, italic, ul, pH, pH_min', "media_buttons" => false, "textarea_rows" => 8, "tabindex" => 4 ) ); ?>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work - the above editor simply displays the same buttons as every other instance on the page.

---

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You pretty much had it, according to the description.

Here's what you might be looking for for instances 2 and 3 (for instance 1 you can leave the settings empty to get the default set of buttons):

Instance 2:

```
wp_editor(
    $distribution,
    'distribution',
    array(
      'media_buttons' => false,
      'textarea_rows' => 8,
      'tabindex' => 4,
      'tinymce' => array(
        'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold, italic, ul, pH, temp',
      ),
    )
);
```

Instance 3 (showing each of the 4 rows you can set for TinyMCE):

```
wp_editor(
    $distribution,
    'distribution',
    array(
      'media_buttons' => false,
      'textarea_rows' => 8,
      'tabindex' => 4,
      'tinymce' => array(
        'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold, italic, ul, min_size, max_size',
        'theme_advanced_buttons2' => '',
        'theme_advanced_buttons3' => '',
        'theme_advanced_buttons4' => '',
      ),
    )
);
```

I recommend that you check out the `wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php` file (specifically the `editor_settings` function on line 126) in order to understand how WP parses the settings you use inside the wp_editor() function. Also, check [this page](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration) to understand more about the functionality of TinyMCE and its init options (which I don't believe WP support fully).

Comment: Hi mate. Thanks for the response. I've added some code to my original post which I believe, judging from your answer, should work - but doesn't. Could you have a look?

Comment: I forgot to wrap the tinymce-specific parameters into their own array. I've edited the answer and added the other parameters you've know put on your question. Let me know how it goes?

Comment: Also bear in mind that others ( me! ) would like to know how to do this ourselves, so try not to devolve into an answer that is specific to dunc and only dunc. Can you add links to any relevant WP/TinyMCE documentation?

Comment: Great, this appears to work. Unfortunately my buttons aren't, but that's a separate question :) Thanks tbuteler.

Comment: You're welcome! @TomJNowell, I've added one last paragraph with recommended reading, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Nearly forgot to award you the bounty :) New question is up here if you have any ideas: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48782/registering-custom-tinymce-buttons-for-admin-area-to-work-with-custom-instance

Comment: Toolbars names have changed: now you should use `toolbar1`, 2, 3, and 4 :-)

Answer (score 10):

you can set the params via array on the wp_editor() function; an exmaple

```
$settings = array(
    'tinymce'       => array(
        'setup' => 'function (ed) {
            tinymce.documentBaseURL = "' . get_admin_url() . '";
        }',
    ),
    'quicktags'     => TRUE,
    'editor_class'  => 'frontend-article-editor',
    'textarea_rows' => 25,
    'media_buttons' => TRUE,
);
wp_editor( $content, 'article_content', $settings );
```

You can set the values via array in the param 'tinymce',
'tinymce' => true, // load TinyMCE, can be used to pass settings directly to TinyMCE using an array()
Also it is possible to get about the params of buttons:
`theme_advanced_buttons1`, `theme_advanced_buttons2`, `theme_advanced_buttons3`, `theme_advanced_buttons4`

```
array( 'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold, italic, ul, pH, temp' )
```

also you can get via filter hook to create custom buttons, also an example

```
function fb_change_mce_options($initArray) {
    // Comma separated string od extendes tags
    // Command separated string of extended elements
    $ext = 'pre[id|name|class|style],iframe[align|longdesc|name|width|height|frameborder|scrolling|marginheight|marginwidth|src]';
    if ( isset( $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] ) ) {
        $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',' . $ext;
    } else {
        $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = $ext;
    }
    // maybe; set tiny paramter verify_html
    //$initArray['verify_html'] = false;
    return $initArray;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'fb_change_mce_options' );
```

also you can filter the buttons directly; each line have an each filter:
`mce_buttons`, `mce_buttons_2`, `mce_buttons_3`, `mce_buttons_4`

the follow params are the default for the example on hook: `tiny_mce_before_init`

```
'mode' => 'specific_textareas'
'editor_selector' => 'theEditor'
'width' => '100%'
'theme' => 'advanced'
'skin' => 'wp_theme'
'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold,italic,strikethrough,|,bullist,numlist,blockquote,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,link,unlink,wp_more,|,spellchecker,fullscreen,wp_adv'
'theme_advanced_buttons2' => 'formatselect,underline,justifyfull,forecolor,|,pastetext,pasteword,removeformat,|,media,charmap,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,wp_help'
'theme_advanced_buttons3' => ''
'theme_advanced_buttons4' => ''
'language' => 'de'
'spellchecker_languages' => 'English=en,Danish=da,Dutch=nl,Finnish=fi,French=fr,+German=de,Italian=it,Polish=pl,Portuguese=pt,Spanish=es,Swedish=sv'
'theme_advanced_toolbar_location' => 'top'
'theme_advanced_toolbar_align' => 'left'
'theme_advanced_statusbar_location' => 'bottom'
'theme_advanced_resizing' => true
'theme_advanced_resize_horizontal' => false
'dialog_type' => 'modal'
'relative_urls' => false
'remove_script_host' => false
'convert_urls' => false
'apply_source_formatting' => false
'remove_linebreaks' => true
'gecko_spellcheck' => true
'entities' => '38,amp,60,lt,62,gt'
'accessibility_focus' => true
'tabfocus_elements' => 'major-publishing-actions'
'media_strict' => false
'paste_remove_styles' => true
'paste_remove_spans' => true
'paste_strip_class_attributes' => 'all'
'wpeditimage_disable_captions' => false
'plugins' => 'safari,inlinepopups,spellchecker,paste,wordpress,media,fullscreen,wpeditimage,wpgallery,tabfocus'
```

see on [this link](http://wpengineer.com/1963/customize-wordpress-wysiwyg-editor/) for more infos to this filter.

Answer (score 8):

Just to update this as I had to dig in the wp source files

```
$settings = array(
    'tinymce' => array(
        'toolbar1' => 'bold, italic',
        'toolbar2' => '',
    ),
    'wpautop' => false,
    'media_buttons' => false,
);
```

I think this had changed with Tinymce 4.

Answer (score 3):

```
$args = array(
    'tinymce'       => array(
        'toolbar1'      => 'bold,italic,underline,separator,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,separator,link,unlink,undo,redo',
        'toolbar2'      => '',
        'toolbar3'      => '',
    ),
);
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $args );
```