# Registering custom TinyMCE buttons, for admin area, to work with custom instances of wp_editor

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor, plugin-tinymce

Thanks to [this answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/48709/6344), I am able to use different instances of `wp_editor` to determine which buttons each of my differing TinyMCE instances use.

However, I'm struggling to actually get my buttons registered - they're simply not appearing on the TinyMCE interface the way I think they should!

I've tried two different approaches - putting the code in my `species-profiles` plugin (a Custom Post Type called `species` in which I wish the TinyMCE instances to feature), and putting the code in my theme's `functions.php`.

The code I'm using is:

```
function add_SF_buttons() {
    if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages') )
        return;
    if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
        add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'add_SF_buttons_plugins');
    }
}

function add_SF_buttons_plugins($plugin_array) {
    $plugin_array['pH'] = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/tinymce_buttons/pH/editor_plugin.js';
    $plugin_array['pH_min'] = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/tinymce_buttons/pH_min/editor_plugin.js';
    $plugin_array['pH_max'] = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/tinymce_buttons/pH_max/editor_plugin.js';
    return $plugin_array;
}

add_action( 'init', 'add_SF_buttons' );
```

The code I'm using to initialise the `wp_editor` instance as per aforementioned answer is this:

```
<?php
    wp_editor(
        $distribution,
        'distribution',
        array(
          'media_buttons' => false,
          'textarea_rows' => 8,
          'tabindex' => 4,
          'tinymce' => array(
            'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold, italic, |, bullist, numlist, |, pH, pH_min',
            'theme_advanced_buttons2' => '',
            'theme_advanced_buttons3' => '',
            'theme_advanced_buttons4' => '',
          ),
        )
    );
?>
```

The plugins I'm trying to use all look like this:

```
(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.pH', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            ed.addButton('pH', {
                title : 'pH',
                image : url+'/pH.png',
                onclick : function() {
                    var caret = "caret_pos_holder";
                    var insert = '[pH]';
                    ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, insert);
                    ed.selection.select(ed.dom.select('span#caret_pos_holder')[0]); //select the span
                    ed.dom.remove(ed.dom.select('span#caret_pos_holder')[0]); //remove the span
                }
            });
        },
        createControl : function(n, cm) {
            return null;
        },
        getInfo : function() {
            /*
             * I intentionally left the information of
             * Brett Terpstra, as his code was the
             * foundation for this.
            */
            return {
                longname : "Brett's YouTube Shortcode",
                author : 'Brett Terpstra',
                authorurl : 'http://brettterpstra.com/',
                infourl : 'http://brettterpstra.com/',
                version : "1.0"
            };
        }
    });
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('pH', tinymce.plugins.pH);
})();
```

As far as I'm aware, everything I've done there is correct? Yet the custom buttons fail to appear. I guess I'm doing something wrong - initialising them incorrectly, or something.

[image: How the TinyMCE interface appears]

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied your code into my functions.php, and added a simple admin panel ('Foo') to display the editor. Then I created a new directory inside my current theme for the editor button, and put the editor button JS into the relevant file: `/wp-content/themes/[my-theme-dir]/tinymce_buttons/pH/editor_plugin.js`.

Result: when I went to Dashboard > Foo (the panel I'd created), it worked as expected. Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Code:

```
/**
 * This function conditionally hooks the function that adds custom buttons to the TinyMCE init array
 */
function wpse_48782_add_SF_buttons() {
    if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages') )
        return;
    if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
        add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'wpse_48782_add_SF_buttons_plugins');
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_48782_add_SF_buttons' );

/**
 * Adds the pH button to the TinyMCE init array
 */
function wpse_48782_add_SF_buttons_plugins($plugin_array) {
    $plugin_array['pH'] = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/tinymce_buttons/pH/editor_plugin.js';
    return $plugin_array;
}

/**
 * Load a dummy admin panel to display editor
 */
function wpse_48782_add_panel() {
    add_menu_page( 'Foo', 'foo', 'manage_options', 'foo', 'wpse_48782_render_panel' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse_48782_add_panel' );

/**
 * Callback to render the 'Foo' admin panel'
 */
function wpse_48782_render_panel() {
    ?>

    <div class="wrap">

    <?php

    $distribution = 'abc';

    wp_editor(
        $distribution,
        'distribution',
        array(
          'media_buttons' => false,
          'textarea_rows' => 8,
          'tabindex' => 4,
          'tinymce' => array(
            'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold, italic, |, bullist, numlist, |, pH, pH_min',
            'theme_advanced_buttons2' => '',
            'theme_advanced_buttons3' => '',
            'theme_advanced_buttons4' => '',
          ),
        )
    );

    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

So, you've basically got it right, and you must be doing something differently than what I'm doing in the stuff that you *haven't* talked about in your explanation. A couple possibilities:

1. You haven't put the editor_plugin.js file in the right place. As mentioned above, your path leads to: `[your-theme-dir]/tinymce_buttons/pH/editor_plugin.js` (and the -max and -min versions). Make sure that these file exist, and that they contain the editor_plugin js you've posted above. If you open up your browser's JS console, you should be able to tell at a glance whether you've got the paths right - you'll get a "NetworkError" or something like that if they're not.
2. Plugin conflict. A very rude plugin/theme *may* be filtering `'mce_external_plugins'` and wiping out changes that are made by other plugins (by returning an init array that is unrelated to the `$pluginsArray` passed to the filter). Grep through your wp-content directory for 'mce_external_plugins' and examine what you find; or you could try disabling all other plugins and switching to Twenty Eleven. Note that a plugin could also wipe out your settings by doing something silly at the `'tiny_mce_before_init'` filter, which is the last one to fire before the editor is rendered - look for that in your content directory too.
3. You're putting your code in the wrong place altogether, so that it's not being loaded by WP. I know you say that you've put it in your theme's `functions.php` - but are you sure? Maybe you've put it into the wrong theme or something like that? We all have days like that ;)
4. There's a condition at the beginning of your first function that says: if the current user can't edit_posts and also can't edit_pages, don't show them the buttons. Make sure that you're doing your testing using a user that has at least one of these caps. (Or try commenting out this check altogether, just as a test.)

Comment: OOOOOOKAY! After going through steps #1, #2, #3 and #4, I decided to copy your code letter-by-letter. It made no difference to my plugin, **but for some reason on your `foo` admin panel, I can see my pH button, and it works!**. Any idea what might be restricting this on my Species plugin? I did a search as per your suggestion in #2 but no results are returned for either in any file other than the one instance in my theme's `functions.php`.

Comment: OK, never mind, looks like it's some kind of bug with TinyMCE or `wp_editor`. I commented out all of the instances of `wp_editor` on my Species plugin page (other than the one you used in your code) and my pH button re-appeared. I've then uncommented all of the other instances out, to make sure I can have different instances with different buttons, and it's working successfully. How bizarre!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Boone's excellent answer, I found the exact problem.

**For some reason, when there are instances of `wp_editor` on the page set with `teeny=true`, custom buttons cannot be used on any instance of `wp_editor`.**

If you remove the `teeny=true` argument, the problem disappears.

Comment: Cool! So glad it's figured out.