# Remove HTML editor and visual/HTML tabs from TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

Is it possible to remove the `Visual` \ `HTML` tabs from `wp_editor` and display only the TinyMCE editor?

Basically, right now, I'm using `wp_editor` to display the smallest possible TinyMCE editor I can - only one button is needed, italics.

[image: Current TinyMCE instnace]

What I'd like to do is make that smaller by removing the `Visual` \ `HTML` tabs. Our authors won't ever need the HTML editor and the custom buttons I'm creating will only be accessible from the visual editor.

**NOTE:** For reasons found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/49167/6344), I can't use the `teeny` argument of `wp_editor`.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Try install this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-visual-editor-wysiwyg/
Simple and fast! :D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just set 'quicktags' parameter of the settings array to false.

```
wp_editor('', 'some-id', array('quicktags' => false) );
```

Comment: No idea why I didn't think of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was hunting for a way to disable the 'Text' tab for all users, and nowhere did I see the filter below mentioned.

This worked for me:

```
function my_editor_settings($settings) {
$settings['quicktags'] = false;
return $settings;
}

add_filter('wp_editor_settings', 'my_editor_settings');
```

Answer (score 1):

The code provided by **ungestaltbar** works great, but I wanted it to work for bbPress (2.2.x) as well. I found this to be very easy and clean as well;

In the template files (only copy the files you need from 
**wp-content/plugins/bbpress/templates/default/bbpress** to your theme folder, into a folder called **bbpress**, for example **wp-content/themes/mytheme/bbpress**) you'll find numerous calls to:

```
bbp_the_content( array( 'context' => 'reply' ) );
```

In your template files replace a call like this with (ie. add: **'quicktags' => false**);

```
bbp_the_content( array( 'context' => 'reply', 'quicktags' => false ) );
```

The calls can be found in all form-*xyz*.php files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple, yet clean way

```
//  Remove visual option and tabs
add_filter( 'user_can_richedit' , '__return_false', 50 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide both from view using this code in your theme's functions.php file:

```
//Hide Post Page Options from ALL users
function hide_all_post_page_options() {
global $post;
$hide_all_post_options = "<style type=\"text/css\"> #content-html, #content-tmce { display: none !important; }</style>";
print($hide_all_post_options);
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_all_post_page_options'  );
```

Comment: Hi Travis. This has had no effect on my page, even when I simply add those lines to my plugin's CSS file.

Comment: Quite honestly, I am no coder. This is the code I always use to hide areas of the new post page. I just add it to my theme's functions.php file and have never had any problems. I can tell you though, the css that styles the tabs is located in /wp-includes/css/editor-buttons.css.

Comment: You might want to try to clear your cache after implementing the above code. I have used it in code on a new site today and tested it on an existing site. Both worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

```
add_filter( 'admin_footer', 'removes_editor_visual_tab', 99 );

function removes_editor_visual_tab()
{
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    a#content-tmce, a#content-tmce:hover {
        display:none;
    }
    </style>';
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById("content-tmce").onclick = 'none';
    });
    </script>'
    <?php
}
```